# Extract rows based on last value of row R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm very new to R, so just bear with me.

I have a dataframe df:

```
ID,NUM,REV,HRY
1221838,2556200,17396.979,L
9677461,5562000,0.000,L
9636801,5562215,0.000,L
9713221,5562222,25739.479,L
```

i want to extract those rows, whose NUM value ends with 0. Similarly for 1,2,..9.

In this case output for those records whose NUM value ends with 0 will be `df_out`,

```
ID,NUM,REV,HRY
1221838,2556200,17396.979,L
9677461,5562000,0.000,L
```

Is there any way to do this in R? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substring` to get the last digit to be used as logical condition in `subset`

```
subset(df1, substring(NUM, nchar(NUM))==0)
#        ID     NUM      REV HRY
#1 1221838 2556200 17396.98   L
#2 9677461 5562000     0.00   L
```

---

Based on @lmo's comments and the update in the OP's post, we can create multiple datasets in a `list` with `split`

```
lst <- split(df1, substring(df1$NUM, nchar(df1$NUM)))
```

Comment: To return a named list of data.frames, each with separate ending digits... `split(dat, substring(dat$NUM, nchar(dat$NUM)))`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`'s `filter()` together with `grepl()` to extract rows with NUM having values ending with `0`.

```
df_out <- df %>% filter(grepl('0$',NUM))
df_out
#        ID     NUM      REV HRY
# 1 1221838 2556200 17396.98   L
# 2 9677461 5562000     0.00   L
```